# Is it possible to exclude a type from generic trait implementation?

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to create an error type with a blanket `From` implementation for any `Error`, however since this type is itself an `Error` I am getting conflicts:

```rust
pub struct ApiError(pub i64, pub String);

impl<T: Error> From<T> for ApiError {
    fn from(err: T) -> Self {
        Self(500, err.to_string())
    }
}

impl Error for ApiError {}
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<ApiError>` for type `ApiError`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | impl<T: Error> From<T> for ApiError {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

I assume it is because of the cycle I have created by implementing `Error` on `ApiError`. Is it possible to say something like `T: Error & not ApiError` and exclude my particular type from this blanket implementation for `From`?

If this is not possible I am curious how [anyhow](https://github.com/dtolnay/anyhow) seems to do something similar?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not do this in rust, but there is a work around.

Looking at the docs, [`anyhow::Error`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html) doesn't implement `Error`, instead it implemented [`Deref<Error>`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html#impl-Deref-for-Error) (and similar traits). This allows `anyhow::Error` to be silently converted to `&Error`.

This means it can now implement `From<T:Error>` without running into the conflict you mention.