# Exclude type from trait bounds

Tags: rust, traits

While playing around with Rust and its generics I came along some problem for which I cannot find any documentation.

I have implemented a type `Wrapper` which wraps another type. At some point I wanted to implement the From trait.

```rust
impl<TSrc, TDst> From<Wrapper<TSrc>> for Wrapper<TDst> 
where
   TSrc: From<TDst> 
{
    fn from(other: Wrapper<TSrc>) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

rustc complains with following error

```
58 | impl<TSrc, TDst> From<Wrapper<TSrc>> for Wrapper<TDst>
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

This makes sense if `TSrc` and `TDst` are the same. Is it somehow possible to explicitly exclude `TSrc` from `TDst`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is there a conflicting implementation of \`From\` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to exclude specific types in a generic implementation.

There's not really a general workaround beyond *"do something else"* which would typically look like an inherent conversion method, using a different (custom) trait, or allowing another mechanism for users to access the inner values and do the conversion themselves.

There *may* be mechanisms in the future like [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) or [negative impls](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html) that could allow such an implementation (or similar), but nothing is on the horizon.

See also:

- [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/2189130)
- [Why do blanket implementations for two different traits conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73782573/2189130)
- [Is it possible to exclude a type from generic trait implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73922479/2189130)